# Why can't I fetch bytea values from my postgres db?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbi

I have a DAO with these methods:

```
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO my_test (ba) VALUES (:ba)")
void insertBytea(@Bind("ba") byte[] ba);

@SqlQuery("SELECT ba from my_test fetch first 1 row only")
byte[] selectBytea();
```

When I execute the insert method:

```
    byte[] bytea = new byte[1];
    bytea[0] = 1;
    myDao.insertBytea(bytea);
```

the value ends up in the database.
[image]

So far so good.

But when I retrieve it:

```
    byte[] bytes = myDao.selectBytea();
```

.. this happens:

> ...
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type byte : \x01
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getByte(PgResultSet.java:2135)
> at org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.PrimitiveMapperFactory.lambda$primitiveMapper$0(PrimitiveMapperFactory.java:64)
> at org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.SingleColumnMapper.lambda$new$0(SingleColumnMapper.java:41)
> at org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.SingleColumnMapper.map(SingleColumnMapper.java:55)
> at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultSetResultIterator.next(ResultSetResultIterator.java:83)

I'm not sure what is going on. But when I debug the code, it seems as if the postgres library is has transformed the value from byte array, to string, back to byte array?
[image]

...because the values [92, 120, 48, 49] corresponds to the string "\x01" which seems to be one of the [ways](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/datatype-binary.html) postgres expresses bytea values.

I am using jdbi3 libraries to access the db.
I am depending on the artifact postgresql version 42.2.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBI internal mapper strategy detects `byte[]` return type as *container* type and expects the query to return *array* of byte values. But in your case it is rather a single value returned containing array of bytes.
Solution is simple, just add `org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.SingleValue` annotation to your method.

From `@SingleValue` [javadoc](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/sqlobject/SingleValue.html)

> Indicate to SqlObject that a type that looks like a container should be treated as a single element.

Your particular example will look like the following:

```
@SingleValue
@SqlQuery("SELECT ba from my_test fetch first 1 row only")
byte[] selectBytea();
```